# Rearrange inventory of specific game in steam?

Tags: api, steam

Rearrange inventory of specific game in steam? is it possible or not?
I checked [steamworks](https://partner.steamgames.com/home/steamworks) and steam api for some information but there is nothing about it, only getting items not changing positions.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an API for this functionality. There is, however, a [pull request](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot/pull/316) to the (TF2 centric) [SteamBot](https://github.com/Jessecar96/SteamBot) application that adds this functionality to that project. One thing to be aware of, though, is that this pull request is 7 months old and hasn't been merged in by the project developers. In that time, Valve has made changes that required SteamBot changes due to underlying Steam network changes. This request may or may not work any more. It may give you an idea of what needs to be done.